# Rails table_name_prefix is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm using Rails 4. I have `app/models/admin.rb` and `app/models/admin/retention_email.rb` that has something like:

```
# app/models/admin.rb
module Admin
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "global_admin_"
  end
end


# app/models/admin/retention_email.rb
module Admin
  class RetentionEmail < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

Now I was expecting `Admin::RetentionEmail` to use `global_admin_retention_emails` table however seems I'm still using `retention_emails`:

```
2.4.1 (main):0 > Admin::RetentionEmail.table_name
=> "retention_emails"
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `config/initializers/namespace.rb` with:

```
require Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'admin')
```